# Issues with React hooks/async behavior

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, supabase, supabase-database

There is some kind of a problem with this code, so I've been "debugging" it with console.log(). The result here doesn't make any sense. What's wrong with this code? I was curious why my console.logs in "useEffect" were null, so I"ve checked it along the way and this is strange, because inside the same "if" there is a certain value, but then when it is used it suddenly is lost => null. How? Why?

[image]

```
useEffect(() => {
    getProfile()
    console.log(email)
    console.log(id)
    console.log(type)
  }, [])

  async function getCurrentUser() {
    const {

      data: { session },
      error,
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

    if (error) {
      throw error
    }

    if (!session?.user) {
      throw new Error('User not logged in')
    }

    return session.user
  }

  async function getProfile() {
    try {
      const user = await getCurrentUser()
      
      console.log(user.id);

      let { data, error, status } = await supabase
        .from('users')
        .select()
        .eq('uid', user.id)
        .single()
      console.log(data.type)

      if (error && status !== 406) {
        throw error
      }

      if (data) {
        console.log(data.type)
        setEmail(data.email)
        setType(data.type)
        setId(data.uid)
        console.log(type)
      }
      console.log(type)
    } catch (error: any) {
      alert(error.message)
  }
```

Comment: “type” isn’t set until the state settles. You log it immediately.

Comment: Relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: What do you mean? How does it apply? What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is behaving correctly. The `console.log()` inside the `useEffect` and after that `async getProfile()` call in the useEffect will be executed synchronously. So the first 3 logs are undefined and it is correct. The setType, setEmail and all setters returned from useState, which will update the state  asynchronously (or to be more correct through a closure function), so it means, that the

```
setEmail(data.email)
        setType(data.type)
        setId(data.uid)
        console.log(type)
```

is doing its job. To log it correctly, add the type, id, and email state to the dependency array of the useEffect hook. As the data changes, it will trigger a rerender and call the useEffect again with the updated data.

Comment: Though can it not display null for the first time so that it loads before render/the rest of typescript? How to rewrite it?

Comment: can you try like this: useEffect(() => {
    getProfile()
    console.log(email)
    console.log(id)
    console.log(type)
  }, [email, id, type])